# How do I aggregate rows in a pandas dataframe according to the latest dates in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have a dataframe containing materials, dates of purchase and purchase prices. I want to filter my dataframe such that I only keep one row containing each material, and that row contains the material at the latest purchase date and corresponding price.

How could I achieve this? I have racked my brains trying to work out how to apply aggregation functions to this but I just can't work out how.

Comment: Posted my answer below. If you post some sample data, I can confirm everything works on my end too. If not, the below should work fine (done it plenty of times).

Comment: No problem, if you wouldn't mind accepting my answer I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a multisort and then use drop duplicates, keeping the first occurrence.

```py
import pandas as pd

df.sort_values(by=['materials', 'purchase_date'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['materials'], keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps

1. `sort_values()` by **material** and **purchaseDate**
2. `groupby()` **material** and take first row

```
d = pd.date_range("1-apr-2020", "30-oct-2020", freq="W")

df = pd.DataFrame({"material":np.random.choice(list("abcd"),len(d)), "purchaseDate":d, "purchasePrice":np.random.randint(1,100, len(d))})
df.sort_values(["material","purchaseDate"], ascending=[1,0]).groupby("material", as_index=False).first()
```

### output

|  | material | purchaseDate | purchasePrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | a | 2020-09-27 00:00:00 | 85 |
| 1 | b | 2020-10-25 00:00:00 | 54 |
| 2 | c | 2020-10-11 00:00:00 | 21 |
| 3 | d | 2020-10-18 00:00:00 | 45 |